# Access Control List (ACL) for EJB

Tags: java, ejb, acl, access-control

Is there any ACL solution for controlling Domain Object data access in JAAS controlled EJB ?

In [Spring security ACL](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html) this aspect is implemented. An API needed for ACL the domain object with JavaEE, or an integration solution for Spring Security and JAAS.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure access control lists would be enough. You need to look at a role-based system (RBAC) or an attribute-based access control system (ABAC).

You can then call out from the EJB: *Can my user access this domain object?*, get a Yes/No back and enforce it.

Here are your options
 - Spring Security implements RBAC.
 - XACML implements ABAC. There are several implementations of XACML available (both open-source and vendor such as the one I work for, [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com).).

If you want background information on access control models, you can have a look at the following:

- role-based access control: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) | [NIST project page](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/rbac/)
- attribute-based access control: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_Based_Access_Control) | [NIST project page](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/)

Comment: My need is filtering based on user access. For example a limited user can see its branch data and administrator can see all data. In this case branch is a field in a domain object

Comment: This sounds like attribute-based access to me. If you use XACML, you can define policies e.g.: a user can view data they own. Administrators can view all data.